# Print name of file if second line is empty

Tags: awk, sed, grep

the file looks like this:

```
>5BW0 B
CHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCCCCEEEEEEEEEECCEEEEEEEEEEECCCCCCEEEEEEEEECCCCCCCHHHHCCEEEEEEEC
```

However the second line could be empty.

I'm trying to find the files with empty second lines.

So far I came up with this in a for loop:

```
cat file1 | sed -n '2p' | grep '^$'
```

the problem is that I'm not saving the filename so that I can print it afterwards.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With single GNU `awk` you could try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. I have passed 2 Input_files named file1 and file2 in this program you can pass number of files as per your requirement also.

```
awk 'FNR==3{nextfile} FNR==2 && !NF{print FILENAME;nextfile}' file1 file2
```

***OR*** as per Ed sir's recommendation above could be shorten to:

```
awk 'FNR==2{ if (!NF) print FILENAME; nextfile }' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Simply checking if its 3rd line of a file then move to next file anyways(which means 2nd line is NOT empty). Then checking 2 more conditions if line is 2nd line and is empty then print file name and move to nextfile.

***NOTE:*** In case you need to find files which are having 2nd line as an empty and print their names then make this above code as a `script.awk` code and pass it to run in `find` command too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you show me how you would do it with find? I have to search through 150 files. I just did a for loop: for file in $(ls); do awk 'FNR==3{nextfile} FNR==2 && !NF{print FILENAME;nextfile}' $file; done

Comment: BTW I think you're just missing a quotation mark. But the simplicity of your command is marvelous :)

Comment: @Caterina, your welcome  for working on many files if they have extensions eg: `.txt` you can pass them to code like: `awk 'FNR==3{nextfile} FNR==2 && !NF{print FILENAME;nextfile}  *.txt` not tested though should work IMHO cheers

Answer (score 1):

What about iterating over file names and looking if the second line is empty as follows. The `;2q` part quits `sed` after line 2 to avoid reading the rest of possibly many gigalines of data for nothing.

```
for file in file1 file2; do
  if test -z "$(sed -n "2p;2q" "$file")"; then
     echo "2nd line of $file is empty"
  fi
done
```

You could also pipe a list of file names into a loop:

```
find . -name '*.txt' |
while read -r file; do
  if test -z "$(sed -n "2p;2q" "$file")"; then
    echo "2nd line of $file is empty"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '2{/\S/!F}' file
```

If the second line of a file does not contain a non-whitespace character, output the name of the file.

Or you may prefer:

```
sed '2!d;/^$/F;d' file
```